# Use MariaDB instead of MySQL in my Rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2, mariadb

How can I use MariaDB instead of MySQL in my Rails project?

When I try to install mysql2 gem it returns error,because mysqlclient was not found.

Here some [solution](https://coderwall.com/p/avjvnq), but I didn't found any **libmariadbd-dev** package on my openSUSE 12.3.

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer, then select it as the accepted answer.  Right now, this question shows up in the stats as being not-answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't look like openSUSE has a MariaDB client development package.  You must install  the libmysqlclient-devel package package.  Since MariaDB is tagged as a drop in replacement for MySQL, it would have to support the MySQL clients, though you may lose tiny bits of MariaDB improvements.

It appears that the mysql2 gem should function with the MariaDB client libraries.  Other options are hoping the mariadb-client package is enough, find a 3rd party package for the libraries or installing them yourself.

**Update**
There is now an [MariaDB repository for openSUSE](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=syringa&distro_release=opensuse13-amd64--opensuse13&distro=openSUSE&version=10.1).  It includes a development package, and very good instructions.  Place the following in a file under /etc/zypp/repos.d/

```
# MariaDB 10.1 openSUSE repository list - created 2015-10-20 16:37 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/opensuse13-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Now you can run `zypper install MariaDB-client MariaDB-devel`

---

Your question isn't about Ubuntu, but I'm sure a lot of people Googling Ubuntu (or its derivatives like Mint) will land on this page.  In Ubuntu, you have to install all the packages using the [MariaDB Foundation's ppa](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=osuosl&distro=Ubuntu&version=10.0&distro_release=trusty), but they include all the development libraries and support the 5.5, 10.0 and 10.1 releases.  Then you can install packages such as `mariadb-server`, `mariadb-client`, `libmariadbclient-dev`, and `libmariadbclient-dev:i386` (32-bit client).

The instructions are simple and detailed on the site.  For example, installing just the 10.1 dev libraries in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirrors.syringanetworks.net/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

On linux mint, I was able to install:

`sudo aptitude install libmariadbclient-dev:i386 libmariadbclient-dev`

Answer (score 5):

For recent **ubuntu 15.04 vivid** and **Debian 8.0 Jessie**:

No need to install from a ppa (`mariadb-server` is included), but you have to install `libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev` and `libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev-compat` and configure the gem to use `mariadb_config`:

```
apt-get install mariadb-server libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev-compat

gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mariadb_config

# or for bundler
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mariadb_config
bundle install
```

Comment: Also valid for Debian 8.0 Jessie. libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev-compat should really have a symlink for mariadb_config.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting error related with mariadb_config. Something like

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mariadb_config
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Cannot find mysql_config at /usr/bin/mariadb_config
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
```

You just need to go to /usr/bin directory and run this command

> sudo ln -nfs mysql_config mariadb_config

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` I am able to install with `sudo apt-get install libmariadbd-dev`

I followed https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-deb-files/ to install MariaDB which adds apt repository for maria db.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 5 (currently still in beta), MariaDB is officially supported, which I think should ease the implementation. Although I haven't tried it myself.

You can read about it in the blogpost on the Rails weblog:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/4/16/this-week-in-rails-mariadb-action-cable-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

While installing libmariadbd-dev package is the easiest way, in some OS or package managers it is not available.

For example on a mac with homebrew this is not available.
I found a workaround though.

To install gem mysql2 on a mac you need mariadb-connector-c in homebrew.
This package conflicts with Mariadb symlinks so you need to do:

```
brew unlink mariadb

brew install mariadb-connector-c

cd into the rails project directory

bundle install (or gem install mysql2)

brew uninstall mariadb-connector-c

brew link mariadb
```